# Anchor showing unexpected behaviour

Tags: html, css, image, border, anchor

I used an image inside an **anchor** and wrote the css to display a **5px solid cyan border** around the image when the image was being hovered but the border is not being displayed fully . 
Link of the image I used :-

[Image I used](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jgEejOfEHNtmCLoYC1_uRLGaiWKCCYoj/view?usp=sharing)

```css
img {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}

a:hover {
  border: 5px solid cyan;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><img src="1.png"></a>
```

**Expected output when image was hovered:-**
[image: Expected Output]

**Actual output when image was hovered:-**
[image: Actual Output]

Comment: inline-flex for the link should be enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your image `display:block` (so it removes space underneath it) and then make your link `inline-block` so it wraps the image

```css
img {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  display:block;
}

a:hover {
  border: 5px solid cyan;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><img src="1.png"></a>
```

If you want your link not to move on hover, then start it with a transparent border and then just change the colour on hover

Comment: Pete , when I run my code in stack overflow the border is not displayed around the whole image boundary. Can you please tell me why its happening?

Comment: you're link is an inline element and as such it doesn't surround the image fully.  I'm not sure this is why but I think the case of an image inside an inline element, the inline element treats the image as the height of a single line of text so it only expands to the height of the line height set on the inline element and not full around the image because the image is a replaced inline element

Comment: Thanks your reply made my concept clear

Answer (score 0):

The white-space below the image is called `Inline Descender Space`. It is a space for letters like: `q, p, g, j, y`, and `f` in some fonts. Images are by default `inline-elements` and as such have that descender space aswell. To remove it use: `img { display: block; }`

Comment: But I don't understand when I simply use border for the image the Inline Descender Space is not displayed ?